# Deleting a zipped file

Tags: vba, excel, zip

Is there anyway to delete a zip file using Excel VBA?
I've tried using `Kill  folderName & "\*.*"` but this will only delete the files in a folder and `rmdir foldername` delete an empty folder.
I have this line of code which has the directory of the zipped file

```
dim ws as Worksheet
set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
ws.range("P3").value ' contains the directory of the zip file

debug.print ws.range("P3").value 'result C:\Documents\MyFilesZip  23-Nov-16_18-06-03.zip
kill ws.range("P3").value
```

I've done it that way but it errors saying: `Path not found
 Can you give me some ideas please?

Already figured it out, since the zipped file is hidden, and maybe has other attributes, I've set the attribute of the file first to `vbNormal` before killing it :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This works like a charm:

```
Kill  "C:\Users\gropc\Desktop\test.zip"
```

Comment: But I've already tried this. This returns a `File not Found` error. Thanks

Comment: Which windows are you using? With Windows 7 and 8 it works quite well.

Comment: Well, then make sure that you give the exact path. It works.

Comment: Updated my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

if you wish to delete any zip file in Folder:

```
 Kill  folderName & "\*.zip"
```

Comment: But I want a specific zipped file only.